# How to get print statements to work while running multiprocessing in juypter notebook

Tags: python, performance, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

While Running python Multiprocessing in Jupyter Notebook, I put my functions in another .py file,
In that function i use print statements.
keeping function in .py file allows me to use multiprocessing in Jupyter, but it does not print the in the jupyter.

Is there any way we can achieve this?

```
def func(x):
    print(f'Running for {x}')
    return x * x
```

suppose this is the function.... I want my print function to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you start Jupyter Notebook there are two windows that are opened. One is in your browser where you create your cells and the other is a console window where Jupyter Notebook outputs its messages. When a child process does a `print`, its output goes to the console window.

If you must have the output go to the browser's window, then one method is to have the child process putting its print output to a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance instead of printing it directly. A thread previously started by your cell gets these messages and prints them. For example:

**File workers.py**

```py
def initialize_pool(q):
    global print_queue

    print_queue = q

def func(x):
    print_queue.put(f'Running for {x}')
    return x * x
```

**Jupyter Notebook Cell**

```py
class Sentinel:
    pass

def main():
    from threading import Thread
    from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
    
    from workers import initialize_pool, func
    
    print_queue = Queue()
    
    def printer():
        while True:
            msg = print_queue.get()
            if isinstance(msg, Sentinel):
                break
            print(msg, flush=True)
 
    t = Thread(target=printer)
    t.start()

    with Pool(initializer=initialize_pool, initargs=(print_queue,)) as pool:
        results = pool.map(func, [1,2,3,4,5])

    print_queue.put(Sentinel()) # Put a sentinel
    t.join() # Wait for all printing to complete
    
    print(results, flush=True)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output in Jupyter Notebook's Window:

```None
Running for 1
Running for 3
Running for 4
Running for 5
Running for 2
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```